# Не пойму почему не работает FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь сделать простой файл менеджер. Есть активити и в ней фрагмент с `recyclerView`. При нажатии на элемент идет проверка: если директория, то вызываю метод активности, который заменит фрагмент на актуальный и добавит в `backstack`.
При нажатии кнопки `back` первый раз ничего не происходит. Второй раз -  закрывает приложение.

Код обработки нажатия(В фрагменте).

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (item.isDirectory()){
                        mCurentPath = item.getPath();
                        mOnDirClickListener.onDirClick(mCurentPath);
                        return;
                        }
                       ......
                    }
```

Код в активити.

```
@Override
    public void onDirClick(String path) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FragmentPicker fragment = FragmentPicker.newInstance(path);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment);
        ft.commit();
        mCurentPath = path;
    }
```

Может кто объяснить почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, для установки корневого фрагмента, Вы также используете метод `replace()`.

Вам надо установить корневой фрагмент методом `add()`, а потом уже остальные накладывать поверх него методом `replace()`, пример:

Для установки корневого фрагмента:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content, fragment, fragmentTag)
        .commit();
```

Для наложения фрагментов поверх него:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content, fragment, fragmentTag)
        .addToBackStack(fragmentName)
        .commit();
```